# Why Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector in a circular motion is $0$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, geometry, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

This vector is the sum of two vectors, and I understand why their direction is opposite, but I don't understand why their magnitude is the same.

I know that the direction of this vector is always the direction of the minimum radius, and in circular moition there is no minimus radius, but I want to understand from the defenition of the vector why it is zero.

Comment: You do understand that, in suitable units, The LRL vector is just the [eccentricity vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace–Runge–Lenz_vector#Mathematical_definition) of the ellipse!? This vector vanishes for a circle: pure [geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace–Runge–Lenz_vector#/media/File:Laplace_Runge_Lenz_vector.svg).

Comment: @CosmasZachos  didn't know that. but how can I see it vanishes from the defenition $\vec{v}\times\vec{L} - k\hat{r}$ ? also, I know that if I change $G$ in $k = Gm_1m_2$ then the vector doesn't vanish

Comment: For a given k you may still have a variety of Ls, and hence vs, depending on initial conditions. When those are such that the cross product aligns with $\hat r$, you have vanishing eccentricity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\vec{A}=\vec{v}\times\vec{L}-k\hat{r}$.

The magnitudes follow from the definitions: A circular motion is given exactly when the velocity is given as $v=\omega r$, therefore $\vec{v}\times\vec{L}=m r v^2=m r^3 \omega^2$.

For the other vector, we see that we have a circular motion when the gravitational force and the centrifugal force balance out: $k/r^2=m\omega^2 r$. Therefore in this case $k=m r^3 \omega^2$, hence both vectors have the same magnitude.

Comment: Thanq you. And what if I change G to 0.9G? In this case I know that the vector does'nt vanishes, but it is still a ircular motion and it should still vanish according to your explanation, I think..

Comment: Why would the LRL vector not vanish, if G was changed? I think you have to take into account that with a new gravitational constant $G^\prime=0.9G$, the whole setting would change: To have a stable circular orbit, the velocity and radius of the orbiting object change.

If you would just randomly "switch" the gravitational constant, a dynamic situation would evolve in which the orbiting planet likely goes in an elliptic orbit.